# Malformed string exception Firebird + linq

Tags: c#, linq, exception, firebird

I try to execute simple LINQ query like this

```
var images = context.IMAGES;
images = from img in images
         join imt in context.IMAGE_TAG on img.ID equals imt.ID_IMAGE
         where tags.Any(tag => imt.TAGS.NAME.Contains(tag))
         select img;
```

When firebird adapter translates to SQL query it tries to cast my cyrillic text to utf-8 like this

```
CAST(_UTF8'тату' AS VARCHAR(8191)) AS "C1"
```

and I get

> "Dynamic SQL Error\r\nSQL error code = -104\r\nMalformed string"

**UPDATED:**
Generated query:

```
SELECT "C"."ID" AS "ID", "C"."GUID" AS "GUID", "C"."EXT" AS "EXT", "C"."ID_USER" AS "ID_USER", "C"."IS_NEW" AS "IS_NEW"FROM  "IMAGES" AS "C"INNER JOIN "IMAGE_TAG" AS "D" ON "C"."ID" = "D"."ID_IMAGE"WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT     1 AS "C1"   FROM   (SELECT      CAST(_UTF8'тату' AS VARCHAR(8191)) AS "C1"      FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X FROM RDB$DATABASE) AS "G" UNION ALL       SELECT      CAST(_UTF8'tatuir' AS VARCHAR(8191)) AS "C1"        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X FROM RDB$DATABASE) AS "H") AS "I" LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT        "K"."ID" AS "ID",       "K"."NAME" AS "NAME"        
FROM "TAGS" AS "K"      
WHERE "D"."ID_TAG" = "K"."ID" ) AS "L" ON CAST(1 AS SMALLINT) = CAST(1 AS SMALLINT) WHERE (POSITION("I"."C1", "L"."NAME")) > 0)
```

Simple table for tags:

```
CREATE TABLE TAGS (
    ID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NAME  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

"NAME" column has WIN1251 charset.

Comment: What's your Firebird (server) version and connection charset?

Comment: I use Firebird 2.5 and WIN1251 charset

Comment: What is the full query generated, and what is the definition of your tables (including character sets of **all** columns)?

Comment: I had a nice theory, but if the column is WIN1251, then that theory doesn't fly. What is the connection character set?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It's also WIN1251

Comment: The only other thing I can think of that although the code is using the `_UTF8` introducer, the string following it is composed of bytes from WIN1251. The characters shown in WIN1251 encoding are invalid in UTF8 and as the introducer instructs firebird to interpret the bytes in the string as UTF8, this results in an error.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel could you suggest what should I do to fix it?

Comment: You should use UTF8 connection charset. No idea why you use WIN1251 in.NET world.

Comment: @cincura.net Then I don't see a reason why it uses the UTF8 introducer.

Comment: @cincura.net It works. Thank you. Probably, I don't understand how does connection charset works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you use some non-UTF8 charset for your connection. User UTF8 as connection charset and you're fine.